# Tkinter Youtube Download Manager Doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter, pytube

I just started to tkinter and making real life projects. I want to build an app that receives a link then asks for the resolution that we want. Finally it downloads the video according to our resolution.
After pasting the link, selecting the resolution and clicking the download button it gives an error like this:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'download'
how can I handle this ?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from pytube import YouTube 
import time
import os 

def showStreams(list):
    return list
def getStreams():
    yt = YouTube(entry.get())
    time.sleep(1)
    list = [stream.resolution for stream in yt.streams.filter(progressive=True)]
    
    for i in list:
        mb.menu.add_radiobutton(label=i, value=i, variable=selected_item)
    return selected_item

def download():
    file = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir=os.path.dirname(__file__))
    yt = YouTube(entry.get())
    
    yt.streams.filter(res=str(selected_item)).first().download(file)

       
    

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("YouTube Download Manager")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=400, width=400)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#1EC3D5', bd=5)
frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.7, relheight=0.1, anchor='n')

link = tk.StringVar()

entry = tk.Entry(frame, font=('Courier',10), textvariable=link)
entry.place(relwidth=0.65, relheight=0.95)

button =  tk.Button(frame, font=('Courier',10), text='Search', command=getStreams)
button.place(relx=0.7, relwidth=0.30, relheight=0.95)

middle_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#1EC3D5', bd=5)
middle_frame.place(relx=0.15, rely=0.22, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.09)

selected_item = tk.StringVar()

mb=  tk.Menubutton(middle_frame, text="Choose!",font=('Courier',10) )
mb.place(relx=0.001,rely=0.001)
mb.menu =  tk.Menu(mb)
mb["menu"] =  mb.menu

download_button = tk.Button(root, text="Download", font=('Courier',10), bd=5, command=download)
download_button.place(relx=0.15, rely=0.3)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: According to [the documentation of `first()`](https://pytube.io/en/latest/api.html#pytube.query.StreamQuery.first), it returns either a `Stream`, or `None` "if the result doesn’t contain any streams". So, the result of `filter()` is probably not returning any results. Are there any streams there before you filter? Have you verified that that filter is correct?

Comment: You should first verify that `entry.get()` is returning what you expect. Then, verify that `yt = YouTube(entry.get())` is returning what you expect. Next, verify that  `yt.streams.filter(res=str(selected_item))` returns what you expect. Next, verify that calling `.first()` on that result returns what you expect. Only then can you debug why calling `download(file)` fails.

Comment: Actually the problem is selected_item. That is the öne that causes the problem. It should be contain the resolution but when I print it it gives PY_VAR1

Comment: There are many questions related to that specific problem here on StackOverflow. `selected_item` is an object, not a string.

Comment: I changed selected_item with SelectedItem, it still doesn't work